mediapipe is not detecting faces on Apple silicon
I'm using mediapipe in the standard way:
    # Detect faces
    with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(
        model_selection=1,  # 0 for short-range, 1 for full-range
        min_detection_confidence=0.2
    ) as face_detection:
        results = face_detection.process(image_rgb)
        
        if not results.detections:
            print(f"No face detected in {image_path}")
            return False

On machines with GPUs or Intel CPUs, I'm having faces be detected properly. But if I run this exact same code on my Macbook Pro, I get no detections.
What is going on, and how can I force mediapipe to use the same models on a Macbook Pro as it uses on a CPU machine?
